# Match nested HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing, match

In a C# app, I want to match every HTML "font" tag with "color" attribute.

I have the following text:

```
1<font color="red">2<font color="blue">3</font>4</font>56
```

And I want a MatchCollection containing the following items:

```
[0] <font color="red">234</font>
[1] <font color="blue">3</font>
```

But when I use this code:

```
Regex.Matches(result, "<font color=\"(.*)\">(.*)</font>");
```

The MatchCollection I get is the following one:

```
[0] <font color="red">2<font color="blue">3</font>4</font>
```

How can I get the MatchCollection I want using C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Your regex matches anything and everything into a single group. You should know that Regular Expressions aren't very good at nested stuff like this. You would have a much easier (and cleaner) time using something like HtmlAgilityPack to parse it.

Comment: You should use HtmlAgilityPack instead.  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex on "HTML" is an antipattern. Just don't do it.

To steer you on the right path, look at what you can do with [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"1<font color=""red"">2<font color=""blue"">3</font>4</font>56");
var fontElements = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("font");
var newNodes = fontElements.Select(fe => {
    var newNode = fe.Clone();
    newNode.InnerHtml = fe.InnerText;
    return newNode;
});
var collection = newNodes.Select(n => n.OuterHtml);
```

Now, in `collection` we have the following strings:

```
<font color="red">234</font> 
<font color="blue">3</font>
```

mmm... lovely.

Answer (score 0):

```
Matches m = Regex.Matches(result, "<font color=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</font>");
//add a ? after the * and print the result .you will know how to get it.
```

Comment: With your code I get one item in my MatchCollection with the following value: <font color="#ff8040">fa<font color="#400000">sdfg</font>

Comment: no, are you using vs2010 you can debug it and trace the variable m.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks to @spender I solved it using HttpAgilityPack :D

Comment: This solution can't handle nested `<font>` tags (as the OP requires it to do). Have you tried running it on the sample data provided in the question?

Answer (score 0):

A way with Html Agility Pack and a XPath query to ensure that the color attribute is present:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
String html = "1<font color=\"red\">2<font color=\"blue\">3</font>4</font>56";
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNodeCollection fontTags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//font[@color]");
foreach (HtmlNode fontTag in fontTags)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fontTag.InnerText);
}
```